# Convert js to typescript child component

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have this layout.js file and I want to convert it to tsx.

```
export default function MainLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <MainProvider>
   
            <TopNavigation />
            <main className=>{children}</main>
     
    </MainProvider>
  );
}
```

I have already converted my _app.js to tsx here:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Title</title>
      </Head>
      <MainLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MainLayout>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue when I get when Ichange my layout.js file to tsx is:

```
Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

I tried changing it to:

```
export default function MainLayout(children) {
```

But it says:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I tried children any[] but that didn't work either. I'd like to use the correct type and not use 'any' too.

Comment: Is this `<main className=>` a typo? Also, you should type `MainLayout` props as `function MainLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode; }) { ... }`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js - Typescript interface props pass down to component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71897021/next-js-typescript-interface-props-pass-down-to-component)